# Sealing PLA & oil-based art supplies?

Tags: pla, post-processing

I will be printing an item that's usually made out of resin, but my version will be made out of PLA. Here are some questions I have:

1. Usually, people seal the resin with brands such as Testor's, Liquitex, or Mr. Super Clear, to create a layer that prevents paint or materials from bleeding into the resin over time. Is this necessary for items made out of PLA? Will the same sealant brands work?
2. On these resin items, people steer clear of oil-based art supplies, like oil pastels, because the they will also stain the resin. Does the same concept apply to PLA?
3. Sometimes, certain dyed fabrics or synthetic materials will stain resin. Do these materials also have the potential to stain PLA?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with PLA and paints before. I use mainly acryl-based paints as well as spray lacquers.

### Sealent is not necessary.

While a sealant is not necessary, you might prefer to use a spray on, smooth drying lacquer to get a smooth surface. PLA does not "soak in" paints or colors like resins.